# how can i add a value in an array of object if the date is same in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Input:

```
[ { date: '2019-11-20', deposits: 100 },
     { date: '2019-11-20', deposits: 300 },
     { date: '2019-11-21', deposits: 200 },
     { date: '2019-11-21', deposits: 500 }  ]
```

Expected Output :

```
var Output=[ { date: '2019-11-20', deposits: 400 } ,
 { date: '2019-11-21', deposits: 700 }]
```

if the dates are same i just have to add the deposits and show it under the same date in only once.

How can i do this in NodeJS ?
i tried to do this in multiple ways and i failed. can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use libraries (lodash), it is easier. Otherwise, you can use a Map for grouping, for example:

```js
const input = [
   { date: '2019-11-20', deposits: 100 },
   { date: '2019-11-20', deposits: 300 },
   { date: '2019-11-21', deposits: 200 },
   { date: '2019-11-21', deposits: 500 }
];
const m = new Map();
input.forEach(({ date, deposits }) => m.set(date, (m.get(date) || 0) + deposits));

// and if want to have it as an array, convert it back:
const output = [...m].map(([date, deposit]) => ({ date, deposit }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: :-  I was writing 20 to 25 lines of code to do this and you have made it in just 2 lines Great stuff Thanks a lot